# How to get highest value text while field in same class, id and name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get value from highest while text field in the same class 
I have tried to make a script like this but it does not work.

```
<input class="resbobot" name="BobotY2" id="BobotY2" type="text"value="100">
<input class="resbobot" name="BobotY3" id="BobotY3" type="text"value="80">
<input class="resbobot" name="BobotY4" id="BobotY4" type="text"value="70">
```

JS

```
$(".resbobot").each(function() {
   if ($(this).val()===100) { 
       alert($(this).val()); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".resbobot").each(function() {
 if(parseInt($(this).val())===100)
 {
  alert($(this).val());
 }
});
```

You have to check text box value with string data type i.e. ' ' or else with integer data type because you are using equal value and equal type operator.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/h9jap3gp/1/

Comment: Perfect..
Thank you for fast respons and help RGS

Answer (score 1):

The `===` operator compares value and type. Your code is comparing the string literal '100' against the number 100. You can use the `==` operator to ignore the type or use `parseInt(..)` as @RGS suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
var max = 0
$(".resbobot").each(function() { if ($(this).val()>max) { max = $(this).val()}) 
alert(max)
```

Answer (score 0):

=== Checks type and value, == checks value. So "100" === 100 returns false where "100" == 100 returns true.

Answer (score 0):

To find the highest value from the input fields using jQuery, use the following code:

```
var highestVal = null;
$('.resbobot').each(function(){
    var curVal = Number($(this).val());
    highestVal = (highestVal === null || highestVal < curVal) ?  curVal : highestVal;        
});   

alert(highestVal);
```

The above code will work even if the input values are all negative numbers.