# can i get maximum value from text field when text field have same class name and id in jquery?

Tags: javascript, each

i want to get higest value from this text field but 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292912/how-to-get-highest-value-text-while-field-in-same-class-id-and-name)

html

```
<input class="myclass" name="foo1" id="foo1" type="text" value="57"> 
<input class="myclass" name="foo1" id="foo1" type="text" value="24"> 
<input class="myclass" name="foo1" id="foo1" type="text" value="11"> 
<input class="myclass" name="foo1" id="foo1" type="text" value="78">
```

js

```
$(".resbobot").each(function() {   
   if (parseInt($(this).val()) > parseInt($(this).val())) 
      alert ("Maximum value is"+??); 
});
```

Comment: what's wrong with the code you've posted? are you getting any errors?

Comment: First, IDs **must** be unique in the document, secondly you need to clarify your problem _in the question itself_

Comment: Please explain what is not working with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you will need to store maximum value in some temp variable:

```
var max = 0;
$( '.myclass' ).each( function() {
    if( parseInt( $( this ).val(), 10 ) > max ) {
        max = parseInt( $( this ).val(), 10 );
    }
} );
console.log( max );
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rfzejddh/)

Comment: thank you for the answear.. that's i want ..
but how to get id , in higest value text field if id different?
like this
<input class="myclass" name="foo1" id="foo1" type="text" value="57"> 
<input class="myclass" name="foo1" id="foo2" type="text" value="24"> 
<input class="myclass" name="foo1" id="foo3" type="text" value="11"> 
<input class="myclass" name="foo1" id="foo4" type="text" value="78">

Comment: Create new value `maxId` for example and assign it like: `maxID = max = $( this ).attr('id');` in if condition. http://jsfiddle.net/rfzejddh/1/

Comment: thank you again..
i already fount solution.. just add maxid = $( this ).attr('id');
thanks antyrat... god bless you